# How to send email with condition in editable email notification

Tags: jenkins

I have job in jenkins with editable email notification post step, but email is sending every time when job is triggered. So question is how to send mail only once per day (lets say 08:00AM) and left othere job runs without email notification. Should condition be in 'pre-steps'? 
thanks

Comment: How many times is your job triggering at day?  What is the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding such groovy code in 'pre-send' script

```
def mydate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(mydate);
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if( hour>7 && hour<9 ){
  cancel=cancel}
else{
cancel=true}
```

So job will send email report only if it triggered in time from 7AM-9AM
 cancel boolian stands for letting jenkins know if report should be send or not